# Ошибка при npm start

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

При команде **npm start** такая ошибка

[image: не разобрался как вставить код в сообщение, поэтому скрин]

После обновления до 5ой версии при **npm start**

```
> csssr-project-template@0.25.0 start /home/atomr/must/new-project
```

> gulp --debug

```
[22:02:15] Requiring external module babel-register
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npm-install-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (webpack.conf.js:23:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (/home/atomr/must/new-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/atomr/must/new-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/atomr/must/new-project/tasks/scripts.js:23:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (/home/atomr/must/new-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/atomr/must/new-project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
```

после `npm i`

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /browser-sync/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /stylint/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
```

Comment: может под latest version там уже 4x/5x нода подразумевается?

Comment: @kroder а как обновить? на оф сайте .xz архив, но что с ним делать? извиняюсь, второй день просто пытаюсь познакомиться с грантом

Comment: да я тоже не бог весть какой жаваскриптер серверный) судя по скрину убунта ведь, там можно в две строки все ставить пакетами https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: @kroder да 5ой версии обновил, все равно такая же ошибка :\

Comment: А что было на в выводе 3-4 строчки выше? Вангую там есть что-то существенное

Comment: @DmitriySimushev обновил, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Я же говорил. `Cannot find module 'npm-install-webpack-plugin'` означает что один из модулей не найден. `npm i` делали?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev обновил ( странно, что код не форматируется как нужно в вопросе, либо я бездарь)

Comment: `WARN` не является ошибкой. Problem solved =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev но npm все также не запускается же)

Comment: Ну так запустите `npm i && npm start`. А уже после этого **четко** сформулируйте что именно у вас не работает. Ну и заодно, как именно оно должно работать

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я просто только знакомлюсь с npm и ничего не понимаю в этом, вчера запускалось без ошибок, сегодня не хочет. Я так понимаю, что бы понять что такое npm его нужно для начала запустить. после команды `npm i && npm start` такая же ошибка, как на скрине, только изменилось на `Exit status 1`

Comment: Вы не до 5.6.0 обновились, часом? На 5.5.0 работает?

Comment: @D-side 5.7.0 сейчас, а как откатиться на 5.5.0? Говорят, что ошибка в том, что из под рута установил, может быть из за этого?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась полнейшей переустановкой ноды и удалением модулей